# React native text input. Text jumps whenever characters are entered into the input

Tags: react-native, textinput

The following video explains what is going on https://www.loom.com/share/c9144a0877b1460c8c02c301afdc3029
There is a noticeable jump in the text when the text is entered. This is what the code for the text input looks like. i already tried scrollenabled=false. Any ideas would be welcome.

```
 <TextInput
        placeholder={'What do you want to talk about?'}
        placeholderTextColor={'#9A9A9A'}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        multiline={true}
        autoFocus={true}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        style={[styles.textInputPost, postVideoUri.length > 0 || postImage.length > 0 ? { height: '20%' } : {}]}
      />
```

Comment: Could you show us the onChangeText handlers code aswell?

Comment: const [postText, setPostText] = useState('');  

const onChangeText = (text: string) => {
    setPostText(text);
  };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, because you are using `useState` hook to manage the state, some re-renders happen and that is why that happens. Maybe try something like this:

```
  const [postText, setPostText] = useState('');
  const [postVideoUri, setPostVideoUri] = useState('');
  const [postImage, setPostImage] = useState('');

  const onChangeText = useCallback((text) => {
    setPostText(text);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="What do you want to talk about?"
        placeholderTextColor="#9A9A9A"
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        multiline
        autoFocus
        scrollEnabled
        style={[
          styles.textInputPost,
          postVideoUri.length > 0 || postImage.length > 0 ? { height: '20%' } : {},
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: This is a solution that does seem to improve the problem. I did see some jump on simulator but that could have been just the autocorrect. i am going to deploy this answer on the device and if it functions well there, i will accept it.

Comment: sorry this has not solved the problem :( https://www.loom.com/share/d6c16b9da9694d479ec0b4636117dc1b

Comment: actually it did contribute to the ultimate fix. so Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It behaves like that because you are probably calling the `setState()` function directly on change, which triggers a re-render every time you edit text input content. For text inputs, I recommend to use the React-Hook-Form library and use Controller to make it controlled input; then it should work fine.

Comment: thank you for your response. This could be "a" solution but i feel its too heavy handed to be deployed as "the" solution. If useCallback as suggested by @MarkoPI above works, it would be more efficient right?

Answer (score 0):

ok so i found a solution. it has two components.

1. use useCallback() for onchangeText function.
2. provide  a width component for the textInput field. That is critical for the solution to work. With both of these things, it will not jump.

   ```
    textInputPost: {
   fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
   fontSize: 18,
   lineHeight: 30,
   alignItems: 'flex-start',
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
   height: '38%',
   **width: windowWidth - 40,**
   paddingRight: 20,
   ```

   },